# @RequestBody, sending in List<String> in POST request

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a basic POJO with a field shown below:

```
@NotEmpty
@ElementCollection
@Column(name = "TAGS")
private List<String> tags;
```

I'm trying to send a JSON formatted POST request to the following controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/post", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void createPost(@RequestBody BlogPost blogPost) {
    blogPostService.addPost(blogPost);
}
```

My JSON:

```
{
    "stuff": "stuff",
    "stuff": "stuff",
    "tags": [{"Tag 1"}, {"Tag 2"}]
}
```

Basically my issue is that I have no idea how to convert that in to a List. I have tried searching for answers but I haven't found anything. Is this even possible?

The error I get is:

> JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token;

Comment: The array objects are malformed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"tags": [{"Tag 1"}, {"Tag 2"}]
```

correspond to an array of object, not an array of String that should be represented like :

```
"tags": ["Tag 1", "Tag 2"]
```

Either change the client side to send an array of String : `"tags": ["Tag 1", "Tag 2"]`.

Otherwise, change the client side and the backend side to declare a List that is parameterized with a custom class that will contain the String value.

Json to send :

```
"tags": [{"value": "Tag 1"}, {"value": "Tag 2"}]
```

mapping in the back end :

```
private List<MyObject> tags;
```

Where `MyObject` could be declared :

```
public class MyObject{
   private String value;
   ... // getter - setter
}
```

Comment: Wow, yeah... Was looking at a lot of code where people were dealing with objects so I kinda overlooked the obvious. Thank you so much for taking your time and replying.

Comment: You are welcome :) It is a simple question. It is very likely. if it may help you to remember about that,  in JavaScript,  `var a = { }` creates a object stored in a `a` variable.

Answer (score 2):

you have list of strings in your pojo but send list of objects
remove the brackets

```
{
"stuff": "stuff",
"stuff": "stuff",
"tags": ["Tag 1", "Tag 2"]
}
```

Comment: Your answer is also fine. It deserves also an upvote :)